# Converting date using .toISOString() doing nothing?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, iso8601

This is doing my head in and I don't know why it's happening - would love some insight.

This works fine for converting the current date and time into ISO8601 format:

```
var today = new Date().toISOString();
console.log(today);
```

However, that method fails if I alter the created date before converting it. Is it because this method must be used on date creation?

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
tomorrow.toISOString();
console.log(tomorrow);
```

The output will be a non converted date string for tomorrows date (the +1 simply increments the day by one, after creating the date).

For the love of god, WHY!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toISOString()` returns a `String`, but does not alter the original object.

Instead of doing...

```
...
tomorrow.toISOString();
console.log(tomorrow);
```

Just do

```
console.log(tomorrow.toISOString());
```

Comment: Marked this as accepted answer (although both answers are correct) because it also explains **why** I was logging the wrong thing. Thanks to both Marcelo and @Daniel Kmak

Answer (score 2):

You simply log wrong thing. You should log `tomorrow.ToISOString()` instead of `tomorrow`:

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
console.log(tomorrow.toISOString());
```

Output:

> 2015-11-06T11:29:31.136Z